# How to show that $I = \langle x^2+2\rangle \subseteq \mathbb{Z}[x]$ is a prime ideal WITHOUT proving that $x^2+2$ is irreducible?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals

> How to show that $I = \langle x^2+2\rangle \subseteq \mathbb{Z}[x]$ is a prime ideal WITHOUT proving that $x^2+2$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$?

I know how to show it by showing that it is irreducible, but how do I show it is prime without showing that? Do I assume it's not prime and get a contradiction? Like, take $a,b\in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ such that $ab\in \langle2+x^2\rangle. $ I want to show that $a\in\langle 2+x^2\rangle$ or $b\in \langle 2+x^2\rangle$ (i.e. either $a$ or $b$ is of the form $r(x^2+2), r\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$). I'll use contradiction. Assume $a\not\in\langle x^2+2\rangle$ and $b\not\in \langle x^2+2\rangle.$ Then $a$ and $b$ are not of the form $r(x^2+2),r\in\mathbb{Z}[x].$  I know we can't use the division algorithm since $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is not a euclidean domain.

Comment: Note that the division algorithm works in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ for monic divisors.

Comment: @BrianMoehring could you give some hints as to how to prove that the division algorithm works for monic divisors in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$?

Comment: @Gae.S. I'm pretty sure it's not true that EVERY quotient ring of a prime ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is not an ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$. Or if it is true, then how would I go about proving it?

Comment: In short, if $$f = a x^n + \text{ lower order terms} \\ g = x^m + \text{ lower order terms}$$ then either $n < m$ (in which case the division algorithm holds vacuously) or $n \geq m$ and $$\deg\left(f - ax^{n-m}g\right) < n.$$  This allows us to induct on the degree of $f$ given any monic divisor $g,$ in _any_ polynomial ring (not just $\mathbb{Z}[x]$)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We assume $a(x)b(x)=(x^2+2)g(x)$. Let $x=\sqrt{-2}$. Then $a(\sqrt{-2})b(\sqrt{-2})=0$, so $a(\sqrt{-2})=0$ or $b(\sqrt{-2})=0$. Assume $a(\sqrt{-2})=0$ (a similar argument will work if we assume $b(\sqrt{-2})=0$). Then also $a(-\sqrt{-2})=0$ [this part takes a little justification]. So $a(x)$ is a multiple of both $x-\sqrt{-2}$ and $x+\sqrt{-2}$, hence of $(x-\sqrt{-2})(x+\sqrt{-2})$, which is $x^2+2$, done.

Comment: It would seem to me that the main part of this proof are the missing details of why $a(-\sqrt{-2})=0.$  Can you fill out those details?  (the common proof I know uses that $x^2 + 2$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{R},$ which doesn't seem to be in the spirit of OP's request)

Comment: @Brian, let $f(x)$ be any polynomial with integer coefficients. Then $f(\sqrt{-2})=r+s\sqrt{-2}$ for some integers $r,s$, and $f(-\sqrt{-2})=r-s\sqrt{-2}$. So $f(\sqrt{-2})=0$ means $r+s\sqrt{-2}=0$ which implies $r=s=0$ whence $r-s\sqrt{-2}=0$ so $f(-\sqrt{-2})=0$. All I've used here is that if a complex number is zero then its real and imaginary parts are both zero.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the ring homomorphism $f:\mathbb Z[x] \to \mathbb C$ induced by $x \mapsto \sqrt{2}\,i$. Then $\mathbb Z[x]/\ker f$ is certainly a domain and so $\ker f$ is a prime ideal. Prove that $\ker f =  \langle x^2+2\rangle$.

Comment: That would be my argument, too.

Comment: the thing is, this is too advanced for me. gerry myerson's approach is much easier for me to understand.